# Wireless Firmware Missing on G4 Powerbook 12"

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I have a 12" G4 Powerbook (867 MHz, 1.1 GB RAM) that I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on.  I can't get the wifi to work, however.  I've followed the instructions in the wiki (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) to install the b43 legacy firmware.  I have a Broadcom card, chip ID BCM4309

When I try to turn on wifi, the manager tells me that the firmware is missing.  If I try to install and update, apt-get tells me that I have the latest version of the firmware.  Is there something I'm missing?  How can I get wifi to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... after a shut down and starting the computer (as opposed to just restarting) it appears to be working now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that shutting down completely and then booting, as opposed to just choosing 'restart' from the power options, allowed the drivers to load.  I now have wifi!